DataFrameWriter.partitionBy does not guarantee sort order
I have a dataset that have the following schema:
(timestamp, partitionKey, logValue)
I want to have the dataset to be sorted by timestamp, but write to file in the follow directory layout:
outputDir/partitionKey/files
The output file only contains logValue, that is, timestamp is used for
sorting only and is not used for output.
(FYI, logValue contains textual representation of timestamp which is not sortable)
However, as mentioned in Spark issue SPARK-44512, DataFrameWriter.partitionBy does not guarantee the output is globally sorted.
(note: I found that even setting spark.sql.optimizer.plannedWrite.enabled=false still does not guarantee sorted result in low memory environment)
And the developers say DataFrameWriter.partitionBy does not guarantee
sorted results:
"Although I understand Apache Spark 3.4.0 changes the behavior like the above, I don't think there is a contract that Apache Spark's partitionBy operation preserves the previous ordering."
To workaround this problem, I have to resort to creating a hadoop output format by extending org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat and output the file by saveAsHadoopFile:
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat;

public final class PartitionedMultipleTextOutputFormat<K, V>
extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<K, V> {
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingJavadocMethod")
    public PartitionedMultipleTextOutputFormat() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object generateActualKey(final K key, final V value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(final K key, final V
value, final String leaf) {
        return new Path(key.toString(), leaf).toString();
    }
}

private static Tuple2<String, String> mapRDDToDomainLogPair(final Row row) {
    final String domain = row.getAs("partitionKey");
    final var log = (String) row.getAs("logValue");
    return new Tuple2<String, String>(domain, log);
}

dataset
.sort("timestamp")
.javaRDD()
.mapToPair(TheClass::mapRDDToDomainLogPair)
.saveAsHadoopFile(outputPath, String.class, String.class,
    PartitionedMultipleTextOutputFormat.class, GzipCodec.class);

Which seems to be clumsy, and slower than using DataFrameWriter.partitionBy directly. Is there any better way?

If your logs same partitionKey is distributed across multiple partitions from multiple nodes, to sort it we might required large amount of memory from cluster.
If you want to try out kafka it that cases, send the logs data from spark node to kafka per partitionKey, keep kafka with good number parallelism based on numbers of partitionKeys.  At a consumer side of kafka you can write a log to your required file format outputDir/partitionKey/files.
It will consume less memory as only inflight logs will in memory and timestamp  order is preserved by kafka as you are writing on same time the logs are generated. But you need to setup Kafka for this solution.
Hope this gives you some insight and helpful to you.

I am aware of the memory problem, and this is exactly I need to do. Even I already partitioned the records, each partition would still contain billions of records. I already have a hadoop cluster to store the log and run spark on the cluster to sort it. I just need to have them partitioned and sorted.
Kafka is not solution. The logs I have is on daily batch basis, not streaming. I need to sort the log and deliver them.

If you want to try on Spark, then transform your RDD to MapPairRDD <PartitionKey, Record>. It will make each partition to have exactly same key. Then run mapPartitions operation on your RDD. To transform into <PartitionKey, (timestamp, Record). It will keep the partitions with same key colocated. Then sort by (PartitionKey+timestamp) and store it the your required format. If you still have questions let me know.
